# Select a second file based on the extension of the first file

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a folder with 28k + files in it and it will continue to grow.. These files are all jpegs but the end with weird extensions. example:

```
1234.0001
1234.0002
1234.0011
1234.0012
5678.0021
5678.0022
```

I have the code to manipulate the files the way I need to, but the problem I'm having is selecting the files. For instance, 1234.0001 goes with 1234.0002 5678.0021 goes with 5678.0022. I think it would be fairly simple if there were a set number of extensions, but there isn't. I've seen files with extensions as high as .0301.

I have to pair the files together and pass the file names to another process. If the file extension ends with 1 it can only be paired with a file wit the same name that ends with 2. Such as:

```
1234.0001
1234.0002

1234.0011
1234.0012
```

But not

```
1234.0001
1234.0012
```

Comment: if you could point us to the answer it would be appreciated too

Comment: Totally unclear what you're trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: If someone could point me in the right direction of the question, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I was as clear as mud. Edited.

Comment: You need a method called "CreatePairs" and want to know the best algorithm?  Did I get it right so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your question. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

- You have a set of files using a [NNNN].[MMMM] naming convention.
- They're all `image/jpeg` mime type files.
- You want to group them using a sequential matching algorithm.

Seems straightforward to me. Let's give it a try.

1. Obtain the file list; make sure they're ordered.
2. Start a loop to iterate through all file names.
3. The first file name will start a new group.
4. Whenever you start a new group, you store the current group's main file name (`[NNNN]` in my example) and current index (that would be `[MMMM]`).
5. If the filename being analyzed have a index equal to the current stored index plus one (`[MMMM]+1`) AND the same main file name, then it belongs to the current group.
6. Otherwise, start a new group.

Running this matching algorithm on your sample codes, you'd get this:

```
1234.0001 <- First entry.                         Create group [1]
1234.0002 <- 0002 == [0001] + 1.                  Same group   [1]
1234.0011 <- 0011 != [0002] + 1.                  Create group [2]
1234.0012 <- 0012 == [0001] + 1.                  Same group   [2]
5678.0021 <- Main group ID change (5678 != 1234). Create group [3]
5678.0022 <- 0022 == [0021] + 1.                  Same group   [3]
```

You'll end up with 3 groups, with 2 items each.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting `1234.*` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method for this would be using a for loop and getting the starting name and matching the start of the string.

Try this:

```
List<string> listOfFiles = new List<string>();
        List<string> processedNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("pathtofiles/"))
        {
            // Add to files list.
            listOfFiles.Add(file);
        }

        // Run through each file and get all that match.
        foreach (string file in listOfFiles)
        {
            // Get fileName.
            string fileName = file.Split('.')[0];

            if (!processedNames.Contains(fileName))
            {
                // All files from this point will be the same (but with the different extensions).

                // get all file names like this.
                foreach (string matchingFile in listOfFiles.Where((s) => s.StartsWith(fileName + ".")))
                {
                    // This file matches the one we just got.
                }

                // Set that we have processed this fileName.
                processedNames.Add(fileName);

                // We now start a new set of Files.
            }
        }
```